# Filter Checkbox issue in react js

Tags: reactjs

This is my code for the category filter. I used this in all places.

```
 {categapi.map((data, index) => (
            <Form.Check
              onChange={props.handleSingleCheck }
              key={index}
              name={data.category_id}
              label={data.category_name}
              type="checkbox"
              id={data.category_name}
            />
          ))}
```

It's the function for the handle the checkbox.

```
 const handleSingleCheck = (e) => {
    if (e.target.checked == true) {
      const { name } = e.target;
      isChecked.push(name);
      console.log(isChecked);
      setIsChecked([...isChecked]);
    } else {
      let index = isChecked.indexOf(e.target.name);
      isChecked.splice(index, 1);
    }
    catfilter();
  };
```

[image]

when selecting two categories it is selected. But when I click the more button it opens the modal but the selected items are disabled in the modal.

[image]

When clicking on the checkbox it needs to check both inside the modal and outside the modal. How to do this?

Comment: Are the modal and sidebar consuming the same state variables?

Comment: Yes both are in same state variable (isChecked is the state variable name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `handleSingleCheck` function you are pushing the values and slicing the state variable `isChecked` directly. Which is the wrong way to interact with react state. [Learn more here](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/updating-objects-in-state) (you should treat the state variables as if they were immutable)

Change your `handleSingleCheck` logic as follows:

```js
const handleSingleCheck = (e) => {
    let isCheckedCopy = [...isChecked] // create a local variable
    if (e.target.checked == true) {
      const { name } = e.target;
      isCheckedCopy.push(name) // push the data into local mutable array
    } else {
      let index = isCheckedCopy.indexOf(e.target.name);
      isCheckedCopy.splice(index, 1); // slice the mutable array
    }
    console.log(isCheckedCopy);
    setIsChecked([...isCheckedCopy]); // change isChecked state through setIsChecked(...)
    catfilter();
  };
```

Comment: Filters are working properly, but the checkbox is not checked what is the reason? If I click the checkbox in the modal it checks but in the sidebar it's not checked.

Comment: I think you have to pass `value` or `checked` prop (depends on library that you are using) in the `<Form.Check />`. So, it knows that user has selected the checkbox.

Comment: `isChecked` is not a `boolean` (I'm assuming that based on your `handleSingleCheck` function). it's an array so you have to use `isChecked.some()` which returns `boolean` based on the value that you are comparing with. If it is present inside the array or not. So, if I assume `data.category_name` being the value to compare, you can say `checked={isChecked?.some((name) => name === data.category_name)}`. See if this works.